# How to make cucumber test steps run half steps only on Chrome and rest of the steps on different browsers?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cucumberjs

My cucumber tests has multiple steps. For example a test like below:

```
Given I navigate to my setup application
And I published an article
When I open client website
Then I can see the published article
```

Step1 & Step2 are setup steps that need to run on a setup website and only on chrome once to create setup for scenario. And once it is done then step3 & Step4 needs to be check on different browsers/devices (IE,Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Mobile) on client website.

My framework is in Cucumber and JavaScript. How I can achieve this in cucumber that some steps of scenario run only on chrome once and rest of the steps should run on different devices and browsers ?

I believe i can't use Before and after hooks as setup steps differ for each test however, before and after hooks run for all the tests in the framework.Also, can't use background as again background will be background for all the tests in each feature file. But in my case , each test has different setup.

Comment: Are all these steps independent ?

Comment: Each step needs execution of previous one . like in first step we are opening up application. If application won't open then 2nd step can't execute which is creation of article on the website opened in 1st step. Similarly to execute 3rd step, it is required that 1st and 2nd steps must have been executed. As if article is not created then there is no need to open client application and view created article there

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need your first two steps in this particular scenario to go through a browser. Surely you know that a published article is just a record in your datastore. Of course you probably have scenarios that show you can create the article using your web interface e.g.

```
Scenario: Create article
  Given I can create an article
  When I create an article
  Then I should have created an article
```

but once you have these you no longer need to go through your web interface each time you need an article creating. Instead you can shortcut the process either by

1) Calling directly the service that creates the article (preferred)
2) Writing directly to the database to create the appropriate article record

So your scenario would become something like

```
Scenario: View my published article
  Given I have published an article  # shortcuts and does not use a browser
  When I view my article             # uses a browser
  Then ...
```

Now your scenario only uses one browser and you problem has gone away. You can now use a variety of techniques to do ensure you can view articles in various browsers.

This pattern of shortcutting for Givens and only using the UI for When's has the added benefit of making your scenarios much faster. You can't use it easily for every Given, some things like 'Given I am logged in' need to go through the browser, but the vast majority of Givens can be shortcut.

Comment: We already have this approach in framework where required. But the scenarios where it can't be used is because we do have two applications, used by two type of users. so first site where data is created by one type of users and is required necessary to verify.

Comment: so what, are you saying you don't have a test environment for both sites where you can write directly to the database, or that you don't know about the responses the first site will give to requests from the second site. If you have either of these you can shortcut and/or mock/store the response from the first site (look at VCR https://github.com/vcr/vcr). There really is no need to go to two sites with two different browsers in one scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it is good idea, but this is what you want:

```
Scenario Outline: Multiple browsers
  Given I navigate to my setup application
  And I published an article
  When I open client website with "<browser>"
  Then I can see the published article with "<browser>"

Examples:
 | browser  |
 | IE       |
 | Chrome   |
 | Firefox  |
 | Safari   | 
 | Mobile   |
```

See https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/#using-variables-and-examples

In the step definition you must setup proper webdriver. Check https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Comment: The way you have designed Scenario Outline, it will execute actual scenario 5 times and each time, all the steps of a complete scenario would execute with in same browser not as per asked query.

Comment: I don't think so. Creating dependent scenarios is antipattern. Running Background once is antipattern too. If you read my answer properly, I mention there, that it's necessary to setup proper webdriver in step definition and it's possible run one step in Chrome and second in IE.